# How do I insert PHP variable inside jQuery/JavaScript bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So this is my first attempt at using bootstrap i am trying to use "chart_filled_blue" in bootstrap but im having problems including my php results inside the jquery for bootstrap i would be thank full for any help or advice.

MY basic pdo select which grabs the views / date

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT date, views FROM views_by_date");
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    print_r($result);
```

I will limit the select so it will only grab the last 6 or 7 rows

So now my chart_filled_blue.js is this

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function(){

    // Sample Data
    var d1 = [[1262304000000, 0], [1264982400000, 500], [1267401600000, 700], [1270080000000, 1300], [1272672000000, 2600], [1275350400000, 1300], [1277942400000, 1700], [1280620800000, 1300], [1283299200000, 1500], [1285891200000, 2000], [1288569600000, 1500], [1291161600000, 1200]];

    var data1 = [
        { label: "Total clicks", data: d1, color: App.getLayoutColorCode('blue') }
    ];

    $.plot("#chart_filled_blue", data1, $.extend(true, {}, Plugins.getFlotDefaults(), {
        xaxis: {
            min: (new Date(2009, 12, 1)).getTime(),
            max: (new Date(2010, 11, 2)).getTime(),
            mode: "time",
            tickSize: [1, "month"],
            monthNames: ["Jan", "FebBBBB", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            tickLength: 0
        },
        series: {
            lines: {
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 1.5
            },
            points: {
                show: true,
                radius: 2.5,
                lineWidth: 1.1
            },
            grow: { active: true, growings:[ { stepMode: "maximum" } ] }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: '%s: %y'
        }
    }));


});
```

I would like to replace all the var d1 with the views from the db and then the monthNames to the date from the db

What would the best way be to do this ?

Comment: get the data via AJAX from `chart_filled_blue.js` like `var d1 = $.ajax();`

Comment: I dont understand what you mean ? bootstrap inculdes the js file onto the page and prints out a graph using the result form the js just need to try and find out how to edit these results every time the page loads via php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either insert the variable at build-time, e.g. you turn your JS script into a .php file and have:

```
...
var d1 = <?php echo json_encode($results_from_db); ?>;
...
```

Or you use an AJAX call to fetch the results from the server.

```
var d1;
$.get('fetchdata.php", {}, function(data) { d1 = data; });
```

If the `d1` data you're fetching will never change for the life of the page, then insert it at page-build time. it'll save you having to fire off ANOTHER http request back to the server to fetch the data.

If the data does change periodically, then you can combine the methods. Use the PHP-only method to insert the "first draft" of the data, then use ajax to fetch the updates.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace d1 with `<?php echo $result['view'];?>`

Answer (score 1):

populate your database results in the beginning of the php page

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT date, views FROM views_by_date");
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    $result = json_encode($result);
```

in javascript

```
 var d1 = JSON.parse(<?php echo $result; ?>);
```